# Encrypt a string in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to encrypt the following string.

Mystring="adhbegadhjmqadguvaadgaegadguvabdh";

```
string[] varEnclist = {
  "adg", "beh", "cfi", "jmp", "knq", "lor", "svy", "twz", "uxa", "aeg", 
  "bdh", "cdi", "jnp", "kmq", "lmr", "swy", "tvz", "uva", "afg", "bfh",
  "cei", "jop", "koq", "lnr", "sxy", "txa", "uwa", "ajk", "adh", "beg",
  "cfg", "jmq", "knp", "lop", "adi", "bei", "cfh", "hio"};

string[] varDataList = {
  "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
  "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_", "0", 
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "."};
```

is any of the data in `varEnclist` found in `Mystring` means I have to replace it with `varDataList`.

> For eg. if `adg` found in `Mystring` means I have to replace it with
>   `a`

like wise I have to do. 
Below is my code but its not working.

```
public string Encrypt(string Mystring="adhbegadhjmqadguvaadgaegadguvabdh")
{
    string[] varEnclist = {"adg", "beh", "cfi", "jmp", "knq", "lor", "svy", "twz", "uxa", "aeg", "bdh", "cdi", "jnp", "kmq", "lmr", "swy", "tvz", "uva", "afg", "bfh", "cei", "jop", "koq", "lnr", "sxy", "txa", "uwa", "ajk", "adh", "beg", "cfg", "jmq", "knp", "lop", "adi", "bei", "cfh", "hio" };
    string[] varDataList = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "." };
    string strReplaced = "";


    int i;
    for(i=0; i9            {
        strReplaced = StrValue.Replace(varEnclist [i], varDataList [i]);
    }


    return strReplaced;


}
```

Comment: what does "but its not working" mean? what happens? what do you *expect* to happen?

Comment: If you want to encrypt data, you shouldn't roll your own - you should use proven crypto algorithms that are readily available in the .net namespace.

Comment: `for(i=0; i9 {` is not valid syntax. should be `for(i=0; i < varEnclist.Length; i++) { `

Comment: It doesn't even compile, no matter work. Look for `c# substitution cipher` on your favourite search engine and follow the tutorials. If this is for anything other than fun/education then don't do this, this is far from encryption. Use the built in approved methods to encrypt data.

Comment: Use Regex for this.

Comment: @Dmitriy _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._

Comment: @fubo Maybe. But using regular expressions you could solve your task faster, better and cleaner without tones of indian-style code.

Comment: That's not encryption, that's obfuscation at best.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"

Comment: @zaph https://dotnetfiddle.net/NA58Lz :P

Comment: @fubo Lpooking at the `Replace` [.net documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) does not state which argument is the match and which is the replacement. Wow, total documentation failure. Anyway the scheme only works if the input is composed only by members of `varEnclist`. It seems that the encrypt and decrypt terms may be reversed from the usual meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Scan (by chunks of 3 letters), Find (corresponding letter) and Concat (the final string):

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string[] varEnclist = { 
     "adg", "beh", "cfi", "jmp", "knq", "lor", "svy", "twz", "uxa", "aeg",
     "bdh", "cdi", "jnp", "kmq", "lmr", "swy", "tvz", "uva", "afg", "bfh",
     "cei", "jop", "koq", "lnr", "sxy", "txa", "uwa", "ajk", "adh", "beg",
     "cfg", "jmq", "knp", "lop", "adi", "bei", "cfh", "hio" };

  string[] varDataList = { 
     "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
     "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_", "0",
     "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "." };

  ...

  string Mystring = "adhbegadhjmqadguvaadgaegadguvabdh";

  string result = string.Concat(Enumerable
    .Range(0, Mystring.Length / 3)
    .Select(index => Mystring.Substring(index * 3, 3))
    .Select(code => varDataList[Array.IndexOf(varEnclist, code)]));

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome:

```
 1214arajark
```

You can use the *same* approach if you want to encrypt:

```
 string encrypted = string.Concat(result
   .Select(item => varEnclist[Array.IndexOf(varDataList, item.ToString())]));

 Console.WriteLine(ecnrypted);
```

Outcome:

```
 adhbegadhjmqadguvaadgaegadguvabdh
```

Comment: Is it readable ?

Comment: @Rainman it is to me.

Comment: I am sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that;

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var s in varEnclist)
{
   Mystring = Mystring.Replace(s, varDataList[index]);
   index++;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1214arajark
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is your exact requirement hope this helps

```
        string Mystring = "adhbegadhjmqadguvaadgaegadguvabdh";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Mystring);
        sb.Replace("dfd", "a");
        sb.Replace("fee", "b");
        sb.ToString();
```

or this one will help

```
        string[] str = { "dfd", "dfdf" };
        string[] abc = { "a", "b" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            str[i] = abc[i];
            sb.Append(str[i]);
        }
        sb.ToString();
```